# Unity: Set iOSBackgroundMode.None in Project Settings?

Tags: unity-game-engine, ios-background-mode

This seems simple, but I have failed to find it and search results don't seem to yield much. Is this something you can actually set in Player Settings or does it have to be done via script? If this needs to be done via script what would be a good approach? I have looked at the documentation at https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/iOSBackgroundMode.None.html and it does not have a description. Should I be looking somewhere else?

I know how to do this in Xcode but the value changes every time I update the project.

I am using Unity 2021.3.18

Thank you

Comment: well coming from script reference, id expect it to be code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Near the bottom of [Other Settings / Configuration](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsiOS.html#other) there is a toggle field called **Enable Custom Background Behaviors**, check it then you can choose the modes.

Comment: It doesn't let me remove them though. When I build the project it still has Audio, AirPlay and Picture in Picture checked in Xcode.

Comment: I tried this option in an empty project, it worked well, when I unchecked everything, `UIBackgroundModes` was absent from Info.plist. So I guess one of your plugin script adds the property. (Either the iOSBackgroundMode has been set, or the plist file has been modified)

Comment: Let me check again. Also, which version of Unity are you using?

Comment: Unity 2020.3.39

Comment: Thank you. There was a script adding the property. Actually, without this script just leaving Enable Custom Background Behaviors unchecked does what I was looking for.